# How to query groupby in following situation

Tags: vb.net

I have datatable in the following format

```
Id   LocationId  UserName  Startdate
1       10        xz        2017-02-21 09:05:20
2       10        xz        2017-02-21 09:15:20
3       10        xz        2017-02-21 09:25:20
4       10        xz        2017-02-21 09:35:20
5       11        xy        2017-02-21 09:45:20
6       11        xy        2017-02-21 09:55:20
7       11        xy        2017-02-21 10:05:20
8       11        xy        2017-02-21 10:15:20
9       10        xz        2017-02-21 10:15:20
10      10        xz        2017-02-21 10:25:20
```

I want to calculate starttime end time and differnce of time ,

and have show record as

```
Id      locationId  startdate     starttime         endtime    timespan   
1            10      2017-02-21   09:05             09:35:20  0hr 30min0sec               
2            11    2017-02-21     09:05             09:35:20  0hr 30min0sec
3            10    2017-02-21     10:15             10:25     0hr 10min 0sec
```

Comment: Do you actually mean that you have a `DataTable` object in your VB app or do you mean that you have a table in a database?  Also, what are the rules here?  Are you just looking to group consecutive records with the same `LocationId`? Examples are great but we still need a description of the rules that govern EVERY case.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean SQL, I hope the following can help you:

```
WITH TEST AS(
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN LAG(LocationId,1) OVER(ORDER BY ID) != LocationId 
     OR LAG(LocationId,1) OVER(ORDER BY ID) IS NULL
     THEN ID
     ELSE 0 END FLAG
FROM [dbo].[DATATABLE]),`
`GroupData AS(
SELECT [LocationId],[UserName],[startdate],MAX(MI.FLAG) FLAG FROM TEST JOIN
(SELECT FLAG FROM TEST
WHERE FLAG != 0) MI ON TEST.ID >= MI.FLAG
GROUP BY [ID],[LocationId],[UserName],[startdate],TEST.FLAG)`
`SELECT LocationID,MIN([startdate]),MAX([startdate]) FROM GroupData
GROUP BY FLAG,LocationID
```